# How to solve this problem with files in C?

Tags: c, file, io

For some reason, the function `loadPerson` always returns `0` as output.

I think that the problem is related to the variable scores within the struct `PERSON`, but I don't know what the problem is. For example, I don't know if the saving function will save the values of the scores or the addresses (since it is a pointer).

Can you help me in finding the problem?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3

typedef struct person{
    int age;
    float *scores;
} PERSON;

int savePerson(PERSON person, char *fileName){
    FILE *file;
    int result = 0;
    file = fopen(fileName,"wb");
    if (file){
        if(fwrite(&person,sizeof(PERSON),1,file)>0){
            result = 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int loadPerson(PERSON *person, char *fileName){
    FILE *file;
    int result = 0;
    file = fopen(fileName,"rb");
    if (file){
        if(fread(person,sizeof(PERSON),1,file)>0){
            result = 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char fileName[15] = "file1.bin";
    float scores[3] = {2.0,8.0,9.0};
    PERSON p1,p2;
    int i;

    p1.age = 35;
    p1.scores = scores;
    printf("Salvando\n");
    if(savePerson(p1,fileName)){
        printf("Saving OK!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Saving BAD!\n");
    }

    if(loadPerson(&p2,fileName)){
        printf("Loading OK!");
        printf("AGE: %d\n",p2.age);
        printf("SCORES:\n");
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            printf("%f,",p2.scores[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Loading BAD!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please define _"is not working properly"_. Did the program crash? Did it set your house on fire? Did it output something else than what you expected, and if yes, please elaborate

Comment: I'm guessing that it doesn't _always_ return 0.

Comment: Please, provide a more detailed explanation of what is your problem. Expressions like ***is not working properly*** do not help in finding out what the problem is. You should state what is your expected output, what is the actual output and why you say the actual output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the function prototype: `int loadPerson(PERSON *person, char *fileName)`
You forgot to `return result;` at the end of your function.

Also once this is solved, you will encounter issues trying to write array to the file like that. You probably want to update your struct to the following:

```
typedef struct person{
    int age;
    float scores[N];
} PERSON;
```

Comment: Why should I use the structure in this way?

Comment: Because at the moment the structure contains a pointer. So you will write the address of the scores into the file, not the scores.

Answer (score 0):

The failure is nothing to do with the contents of the data structure. There are very few ways in which this function can fail. The following version will let you figure out which is the case.

```
int loadPerson(PERSON *person, char *fileName){
    FILE *file;
    int result = 0;
    file = fopen(fileName,"rb");
    if (file){
        if(fread(person,sizeof(PERSON),1,file)>0){
            result = 1;
        }else{
            printf("File read error!");
        }
    }else{
        printf("File not found: %s", fileName);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Either the file you're trying to open does not exist, or it doesn't contain enough data for you to read one structure. In either case an error message will be printed.

("File not found" is most likely because the file is in one directory and your program is executing with a different *current directory* setting. You'd need to look at your development environment to fix that. A "File read error" immediately after successfully opening the file *probably* means that the file you're trying to read from doesn't contain enough bytes to read one `PERSON` structure. You should get a return value of `1` from `fread` if it reads one item. Check the size of your file.)

Of course, if the function does succeed, the calling code still needs to know that. Your code did not return a value even though the function was declared as returning an `int`. I have taken the liberty of returning the value you clearly intended to use for that purpose. I recommend you look closely at why your compiler did not warn you of this serious problem... or if it did, why you ignored that.